# Regex positive lookahead - pattern that always fails

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am learning regex and I found the following pattern:

```
q(?=u)i
```

If I try to math `quit`, it fails, because q matches q, u matches u (so the lookahead is valid), but then the regex backtracks in the word `quit` and the character u is compared again, this time with i. The match fails.

I don't see any word matching this pattern. Is there any case? Or is this structure (pattern - lookahead - rest of pattern) useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no matching pattern similar to the one you mentioned that I have seen, but such a structure can be used (though admittedly a bit weird), for example:

```
q(?=.*t)u
```

This regex will match any string starting with `qu` but which has a `t` somewhere later. This means that `question`, `quit` will match, but not `quasar`. In which case, an equivalent and more readable (imo) regex `qu(?=.*t)` could be used.

Answer (score 3):

The regex lookaround syntax is [zero width](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

What this means is that it matches but doesn't move the cursor, so in your pattern:

- `q` matches "q" the cursor moves to "u"
- `(?=u)` matches "u" the cursor stays at "u"
- `i` does not match "u" so the pattern fails.

Note that the pattern **doesn't** backtrack, the lookaround assertion is zero width.

The structure is very useful is you wanted to match a pattern that contained, say, "at least one X" in a series of letters. For example:

```
[a-z]{4}[1-9]{3}(?=.*X)[a-zA-Z]{5}
```

Says four lowercase letter followed by three digits followed by five letters of any case with at least one "X".

Answer (score 1):

I would say, if the pattern after(or before) the lookahead (`(?=...)`) is fixed. the regex doesn't really make much sense. like:

```
foo(?=bar)fixed
```

but if the `fixed` part is dynamic, it would be useful. see this example:

```
kent$  echo "fooququuuxxxxxxx"|grep -Po 'q(?=uu).*' 
quuuxxxxxxx

kent$  echo "fooququuuxxxxxxx"|grep -Po 'q(?=u).*' 
ququuuxxxxxxx
```

in above example, only the lookahead is different, you got different match result.

Answer (score 0):

In applying the use case structure presented in this question and the response by Boris the Spider, I came up with this solution

```
$detail = '[code]<!doctype>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body><p>My Regex script</p></body>
</html>[/code]';

function regex($detail) 
{
   if(preg_match('#^\[code](?=.*(<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\2>))\[/code]#si',  $detail))
   {
       return true;
   }
   return false;        
}
echo regex($detail);
```

Taking a look inside the regex engine, this is what is happening. In applying `^\[q](?=.*(<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\2>))[/q]*` to $detail above; `\[q]` matches `[q]` and the html section of the code matches `(<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\2>))`.

The match from the lookahead is discarded, so the engine steps back from [/q] in the string to the html section of the code. The lookahead was successful, so the engine continues with `[/q]`. But `[/q]` cannot match `(<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\2>))`. So this match attempt fails.

However this regex synthax works:

```
#^\[code](?=.*(<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\2>\[/code]))#si
```

The regex engine simply says: "opening `[code]` tag followed by any character, then a pair of html tags with at least a closing `[/code]` tag at the end".

I hope this helps explain the use case pattern match (quit) more.